# How do I get an authentication token for a WorkDocsClient on the AWS WorkDocs API?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, authentication, token, amazon-workdocs

I'm currently working on a project using the AWS WorkDocs API and php.

For some functions, it's necessary to have an authentication token.

For example, the DescribeRootFolders service :

[image]

I've a key and a secretKey to connect to the API via the WorkDocsClient class but I would like to know how I can get an authentication token ?

Of course, I saw that there was a solution to get an authentication token via the creation of an application but I dare to hope that there is another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've an official answer on the AWS Support : Case ID 10537471241.**

> Currently there is no capability to generate access tokens via the
> SDK.
> This may change in the future if full OAuth protocol compliance
> is introduced.